# How to determine stream channel Reach locations?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, hydrology

I have a stream network and want to determine stream reach locations [image: Stream Network]

In attached figure, Reach 4 is at the junction of sub2 and sub5, and Reach 3 is at the junction of sub1 and sub4. Any suggestions to determine these junctions based on confluence points using ArcPy or within ArcMap will be very much helpful.

Comment: Is your network topologically cleaned?  That is, do the nodes and lines touch?  Is your network in a geodatabase?  In a geometric network?  If not, you might benefit from putting it in a [geometric network](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002r00000001000000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used 'Stream Order' tool with order method 'Shreve'. It separated all streams without tributaries and numbered them as '1'. Rest of the streams receive numbers. Now I can handle 'Reach' location and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

You could create a raster of flow accumulation using a DEM and extract this information along the channel network. This can effectively create a plot of catchment area along a channel. Where ever you have a sudden jump in the catchment area is where stream channels are joined.

Probably not the kind of answer you're looking for though if you're playing with networks. Just thought i'd throw it out there as it's something I've done in the past.

Good luck!

Comment: Its not exactly what I am looking for.